Should I send an e-mail showing my interest in the postdoc position if another professor forwards my information?
I sent a cold email to a professor who had already filled a vacancy. He mentioned, however, that he had a colleague with a vacancy and asked if he could forward my email. Of course I agreed, but my question is, do I send an e-mail to this other professor or do I wait for him to contact me?

Why would you wait? Exhibit interest in the position, if you are actually interested. And cc the first professor, expressing appreciation in the introduction.

Send the mail mentioning both the circumstances and your interest in working with them. Offer to send any additional information that they may need.
There is no downside to such a mail.
